# rspec test for checking the file size is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have an rspec test to check the file size of a file that is written by a process.  Here is the test:

```
require 'spec_helper.rb'
require 'lib/sf_to_coll/convert.rb'
require 'rake'

describe SfToColl::Convert do
  context "main file for single record should be 2186 chars long" do
    before do
      SfToColl::Convert.new("tmp/ctbrown.csv", "ctbrown_fwfile").process
    end

    subject { File.stat("tmp/ctbrown_fwfile_main").size }
    it { should == 2186 }

    after do
      File.rename('tmp/ctbrown_fwfile_main', 'tmp/ctbrown_fwfile_main.bak')
    end
  end
end
```

This test is currently failing, although on inspection of the directory after the test, the file exists and has a file size of 2186.

However, when I put in a binding.pry on this line:

```
it { binding.pry; should == 2186 }
```

and add nothing else to the code, the test passes when continuing after the pry.

The Convert#process method takes in a .csv file and produces a series of fixed-width lines which must be exactly 2186 chars long.

Is this a threading problem?  I have tried adding a thread around the line

```
SfToColl::Convert.new("tmp/ctbrown.csv", "ctbrown_fwfile").process
```

without success.

Comment: Does the convert process flush the contents to the file and close it? If not, you may be waiting for I/O to complete this...

Comment: If you puts `File.exists?("tmp/ctbrown_fwfile_main")` in your before block after the process, what do you get?

Comment: PinnyM, you are right on target.  I added a close statement for the file and the test now passes.  **Thank you!**

Comment: Vimsha, I get true whether or not I close the file, but the test fails because of the missing close statement.  Thanks!